# js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an rails application, yesterday I tested all my js and it worked fine, now I make some changes on it and js doesn't work correctly (the code from application.js doesn't execute correctly, the thickbox plugin still works fine), the funny thing is that I get my yesterday version from backup and now the same js problem appears, I check it in chrome and firefox4, anyone has some guesses?

js code:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
var count;
$.getJSON("/carts/on_card", function(data){
    count = data;
    $("#products_count").text(count);   
}); 

$("#first_element").removeClass("page_item");
$("#first_element").addClass("current_page_item");
});

$(document).ready(function(){

var count;

$(".add_to_card").click(function(){     
    $.getJSON("/carts/on_card", function(data){
        count = 0;          
        count = data;           
    }); 

    $("#products_count").text(count);               
});

$(".removable").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});

$(".page_item").click(function(){
    $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
    $(".current_page_item").addClass("page_item")

    $(this).removeClass("page_item");
    $(this).addClass("current_page_item");
})
});
```

Comment: Are you kidding us? Where is the code?

Comment: what did you change and how do you make sure the js code is included in your pages?

Comment: I'll assure you, JavaScript as a whole is still working just fine. Please provide some code, an error, or anything else that we can look at.

Comment: the console doesn't show any errors, the ajax requests works fine but the selectors didn't work

Comment: Yay for version control.

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with the **cache** mechanism? Maybe you are seeing same results because the JS in the cache is still the incorrect one? Or in the other direction - the yesterday's version also contains a bug, but yesterday you were testing the page when the older (correct) JavaScript was still in the cache?

If cache is not the problem here, maybe some other script or HTML is currently different and interacts with the code in a different way than previously (some scripts require specific classes or attributes to be added to the elements they should process).

Anyway, did anything else change since it worked? Maybe you installed some plugin? Maybe you changed URLs? Maybe location of the script? Tell us more.

Comment: I don't think it's cache because I install firefox after this problem appears in chrome, I don't change nothing in my js and html that interacts with it, only installed thickbox, but the same code without thickbox give me the same result

Comment: @Maki So the changes you have made: 1) you have added Thickbox (how? please give us details), 2) installed Firefox (you did not test it yesterday on Firefox, but only on Chrome). Correct? One more question: what do you mean by "same code without thickbox give me the same result"? You mean Thickbox is not working? Was it working yesterday, when you tested it on Chrome?

Comment: I have my yesterday code backuped, now I when I add the thickbox (only added the thickbox at js tag <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "thickbox" %>), the js doesn't work, but the thickbox works fine, now the first I thinked about is the problem in thickbox, get my yesterday backup folder and just run app, and have the same result, described js doesn't work. 
Yes yesterday I tested just with chrome